# Do all of the referenced style and script pages get included also when including another asp file?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, include

If the .asp page the user is viewing uses an include to access a different .asp file, does it also give it access to the style and javascript pages that are referenced in the page you are including?

Example:
If home.asp has `<!-- #include file="bin/utilities.asp" -->`
on line 1 of the page and the utilities.asp page has references to:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="scripts.js" async></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="form.js" async></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Will home.asp be able to use the script and link references?  Will every page of the site that includes the utilities file be able to access them?

Answer (score 0):

User is never viewing the asp page, but the rendered html, which is generated from asp page.

So if you include utilities.asp in home.asp, then yes, home.asp will in fact have access to those scripts, beacause the page will be generated as singe html page with content of utilites.asp rendered from 1st line (where included) - the references to the scripts, followed by the contents of home.asp.

The same apply on evey page that uses include.

If you want to see the HTML rendered, just pres Ctr+U in your browser (Show source).